# cross-sell products on product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, error, page

I am trying to get a tab section done in default theme on a product page, which should display related products, upsell products and cross sell products.

Related and upsell is already working, but how do I add cross sell products.

I have been trying the following:

in layout.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
....
   <reference name="content">
.....
      <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>
```

.....
And I am trying to call it in view.phtm template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell_products') ?>
```

Like this it works for related and upsell but not cross sell. Maybe because it is in a different directory / section?

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79242/add-cross-sell-block-on-product-page

Answer (score 0):

Block name is checkout.cart.crosssell and alias is crosssell.

You have written `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell_products') ?>`

check it

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
```